# Button doesn't respond on first click

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I have a button in the header of my website and it has to open/change another div display state, on first click. But it's not responding on first click and I can't find the bug. I would appreciate some help..

```js
/* show search div */
function ShowSearchDiv() {
  var searchbox = document.getElementById("header-search-form");
  if (searchbox.style.display === "none") {
    searchbox.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("search-icon").classList.remove('fa-search', 'fa-lg2');
    document.getElementById("search-icon").classList.add('fa-close', 'fa-lg-sm');

  } else {
    searchbox.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("search-icon").classList.remove('fa-close', 'fa-lg-sm');
    document.getElementById("search-icon").classList.add('fa-search', 'fa-lg2');
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-rd-nav" onclick="ShowSearchDiv()" id="btn-search-home">
   <i id="search-icon" class="fa-search fa fa-lg3 fa-bg"></i>
</button>

<div id="header-search-form" class="search-form slideInUpbox">
  <!----->
  <form method="post" action="search-results.asp?action=kword&keyw=&pg=" id="frmsk" name="frmsk" class="home-search">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="txtsearch" name="txtsearch" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
      <button onClick="javascript:gosearch()" class="btn-search" type="submit"><span class="fa-search fa fa-lg"></span></button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the function after the window has completely loaded? Switch what is inside the if with else. Sometimes it happens that you might be thinking it on the contrary. The first click might be working, check with console.log(123); inside the function to see if it works.

Comment: Yes, you're right. If I switch the if and else content it works at first click, but then it doesn't work when I click to close it :)
I have to find something else or complete the code somehow...

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug and changed the if statement to:

```js
<script>
/* show search div */
function ShowSearchDiv() {
    var searchbox = document.getElementById("header-search-form");
    if (searchbox.style.display === "block") {
        searchbox.style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("search-icon").classList.remove('fa-close', 'fa-lg-sm');
          document.getElementById("search-icon").classList.add('fa-search', 'fa-lg2');  

      }
      else {
        searchbox.style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById("search-icon").classList.remove('fa-search', 'fa-lg2');
            document.getElementById("search-icon").classList.add('fa-close', 'fa-lg-sm');
         } 
}

</script>
```

This way instead of checking "if the div is hidden, then make it visible and else hide it...", I changed it to "if the div is visible, then make it hidden, else leave it visible :) 
Now it's working on first click.